# How to find nearest marker on Google Maps Activity in Android using JSON Data?

Tags: android, json, maps

I'm using this example to show markers on a Google Maps Activity.
Example: https://gist.github.com/TimPim/5902100

```
void createMarkersFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {
    // De-serialize the JSON string into an array of city objects
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        // Create a marker for each city in the JSON data.
        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title(jsonObj.getString("name"))
            .snippet(Integer.toString(jsonObj.getInt("population")))
            .position(new LatLng(
                    jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(0),
                    jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(1)
             ))
        );
    }
}
```

I would like to reuse this code below to check the closest marker for the JSON information to find the closest marker.
Code below from [Display title of closest marker from my current position Google Maps v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508482/display-title-of-closest-marker-from-my-current-position-google-maps-v2/19508778#19508778)

```
List<MyMarkerObj> m = data.getMyMarkers();
float mindist;
int pos=0;
            for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
                String[] slatlng =  m.get(i).getPosition().split(" ");
                LatLng lat = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(slatlng[0]), Double.valueOf(slatlng[1]));
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .title(m.get(i).getTitle())
                        .snippet(m.get(i).getSnippet())
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                        .position(lat)
                        );

                float[] distance = new float[1];
                Location.distanceBetween(currentlat, currentlong,Double.valueOf(slatlng[0]), Double.valueOf(slatlng[1]), distance);
                if(i==0) mindist=distance[0];
                else if(mindist>distance[0]) {
                   mindist=distance[0];
                   pos=i;
                 }
            }
  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Closest Marker Distance: "+ m.get(pos).getTitle() +" "+mindist, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Should I just add the Lat/Lon to the Array "m" then run the code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `m` array for your case, as you already have your data in a JSONArray.

Simply iterate through the JSONArray, keep track of the current-nearest Marker, and when the loop is done you'll have a reference to the nearest Marker.

Combining your code with the relevant parts of the other answer:

```
Marker mClosestMarker;
float mindist;
void createMarkersFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {
    // De-serialize the JSON string into an array of city objects
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        // Create a marker for each city in the JSON data.
        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        double lat = jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(0);
        double lon = jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(1);
        Marker currentMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title(jsonObj.getString("name"))
            .snippet(Integer.toString(jsonObj.getInt("population")))
            .position(new LatLng(
                    lat,
                    lon
             ))
        );

      float[] distance = new float[1];
      Location.distanceBetween(currentlat, currentlong, lat, lon, distance);
      if(i==0) {
        mindist = distance[0];
      } else if (mindist > distance[0]) {
        mindist=distance[0];
        mClosestMarker = currentMarker;
      }
    }

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Closest Marker Distance: "+ mClosestMarker.getTitle() + " " + mindist, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**Note**
If you need help getting the current location for `currentlat` and `currentlong`, see here: [How can I show current location on a Google Map on Android Marshmallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582370/how-can-i-show-current-location-on-a-google-map-on-android-marshmallow)

If you follow the answer there in order to get the current location, and you have placed a "current location" Marker, you can simply do this:

```
LatLng currentLatLng = mCurrLocationMarker.getPosition();
Location.distanceBetween(currentLatLng.latitude, currentLatLng.longitude, lat, lon, distance);
```

Comment: Absolutely Genius! Thank you so much!\

Comment: @StevenHammons  Take a look at the link at the end of the answer if you need help getting the current location of the device for the `currentLat` and `currentLong` variables